# VSTS - Creating CI for on premise build & deploy - step-by-step tutorial anywhere?

Tags: tfs, build, continuous-integration, azure-devops, definition

I currently store all of my source code in Visual Studio Team Services and I now need to be able to setup continuous integration for our internal development environment. I have searched high and low for decent step-by-step tutorials but cant' quite find one that ticks all the boxes. It is difficult to know what all the settings and fields do when trying to create a build or release definition as some have helpful '?' next to them and some do not.

Anyway, with some trial and error, I have gotten as far as installing and configuring a build agent and deployment group onto my internal server. I have created a build definition and actually got a successful build!

Now creating a release definition is where I am getting totally confused. My solution consists of a UI and an API, both of which need to be published individually. My build definition builds both of these at the same time.

Looking at creating a deployment definition it seems that I can only deploy the whole build and not each individual app? Do I need to create individual build definitions and then attach the separate artifacts to the release definition? Does anybody know where there is a straight forward and clear step-by-step tutorial for configuring CI for the latest online VSTS? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Your question is asking too many things to be answered within the format of this site. Please **[take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and read **[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** and **[how to create a minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** for better results using this site. Good luck!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with 'deploy only the whole build'. Isn't that what you want? You have 1 build that produces 1 artifact which contains both the UI and the API. Why split this in multiple artifacts to end up with one single Release Definition that references both artifacts?

Comment: Questions asking for links to off-site resources are off-topic for Stack Overflow. As such, I've voted to close this question.

Comment: Thank you for help, apologies for not formatting the post appropriately I will take on board the comments and address accordingly for my next post.

Answer (score 0):

You don`t  have to create separate build definition for your projects. You can copy part of your build result with copy rule.

[image]

Then use that for next steps on deploy agent.

As workaround you may create in one build definition several drops (one for UI, second for API) and use it for deploy. But this is more complex scenario that requires additional steps to separate the build results and copy them to needed paths.

Answer (score -1):

Your build definition produces what's called an artifact. The artifact is linked to your release definition. An artifact can contain multiple folders, for example one with your frontend and one with the backend.

In your release definition, you can configure the different tasks by pointing them to the files they should work with in your artifact.

A complete step by step tutorial can be found here: [Continuous integration, test, and deployment tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/example-continuous-testing)

Comment: The link is broken.